# snakemake: Is it possible to signal missing files during generating the input of a rule?

Tags: python, snakemake

I'd like to be able to define additional input dependencies in a config file.
However, when the config file is being generated by a different rule, it cannot be read when generating the input:

```py
# Reads the "depends" section from a config yaml and adds it as additional input rules
def prepare_data_input(wildcards):
    retval = dict(
        config=SNAKEMAKE_DIR + "/{wildcards.ds_dir}/feature_sets/{wildcards.script}@{wildcards.id}.yaml",
        config_depends=MODEL_DIR + "/{ds_dir}/feature_sets/{script}@{id}/data_dependencies.yaml"
    )
    
    retval = {k: v.format(wildcards=wildcards) for k, v in retval.items()}
        
    import os
    if os.path.exists(retval["config"]):
        import yaml
        with open(retval["config"], "r") as fd:
            config = yaml.safe_load(fd)
        
        retval["depends"] = config
    
    retval = {k: v.format(wildcards=wildcards) for k, v in retval.items()}
    
    return retval
```

When `retval["config"]` does not exist during rule creation, its additional dependencies will not be read by default.

Currently, I solve this problem with a `checkpoint` rule that has `config_depends` in its output to force re-evaluation of the rule as soon as `config` is being created:

```py
# small hack to force re-evaluation of rules depending on the config.yaml
checkpoint prepare_data_dependencies:
    output:
        config=MODEL_DIR + "/{ds_dir}/feature_sets/{script}@{id}/config.yaml",
    input:
        config=SNAKEMAKE_DIR + "/{ds_dir}/feature_sets/{script}@{id}.yaml",
    wildcard_constraints:
        ds_dir="[^/]+",
        model_dir="[^/]+",
    shell:
        r"""
        cp {input.config} {output.config}
        """
```

My question now is whether there is some way to tell Snakemake that there is a missing input file beforehand. Something like this (pseudocode):

```py
# Reads the "depends" section from a config yaml and adds it as additional input rules
def prepare_data_input(wildcards):
    [...]
    if not os.path.exists(retval["config"]):
        raise MissingInputFileException(retval["config"])
    [...]
```

Comment: If the rule depends on the input, this file shall exist before the rule is invoked. If the file is the one that another rule generates, Snakemake would fail whenever it discovers that the file was not produced. What are you trying to do on top of that?

Comment: My idea was that snakemake gets an exception that tells it "hey, the config file is missing. Check out if there is a rule that generates it first and then re-evaluate this rule". This way, I could save the checkpoint rule.

Comment: If there is a rule that claims the config as it's output, there would be an exception if it doesn't produce it.